# Re-format date input value to german format with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've an input of

```js
jQuery("#date-input").change(function() {
  console.log(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date-input" type="date"/>
```

the type date or sometimes a datepicker, if input type date is not supported by the browser. The ID's are always the same. So now I'm looking for a way to re-format the received value to the german format.

For example `2019-07-07` to `07.07.2019`.

This is my code:

Do you have any ideas how to deal with this? I've looked a bit around but I can't find a real and good solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can create a Date object from the string value and then call `toLocaleString()` on that. If required, you can force the `de-DE` culture formatting as an argument to that method call:

```js
$("#date-input").change(function() {
  var dateString = $(this).val();
  console.log(dateString);

  var deDate = new Date(dateString);
  console.log(deDate.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "2-digit",
    day: "2-digit",
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date-input" type="date" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I like this one but the date is now 9.8.2019. I'm missing the leading zeros :o.

Comment: alert( deDate.toLocaleDateString( "de-DE", {
 year: "numeric",
 month: "2-digit",
 day: "2-digit",
} ) );

Comment: I was about to say you can use a settings object, but it seems you got it working already :) I updated the answer regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Basically as below

```
jQuery("#date-input").on("blur",function() {
  console.log(jQuery(this).val().split("-").reverse().join("-")); // dd-MM-yyy format
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Hope it helps

```js
jQuery("#date-input").change(function() {
  var val = jQuery(this).val().split('-').reverse().join('.');
  console.log(val)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date-input" type="date"/>
```